# How can we perform following raw query using Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

```
select * from student where totalDays-presentDays > 50;
```

I m performing this above query using sequelize.

I tried this following code.

```
where:
     {
       StudentDB.Sequelize.literal(totalDays-presentDays):
       {
          [Op.gt]:50
       }
     }
```

But It is giving error like **Unexpected token '.' in database name and Sequelize keyword.**

And I also tried this.

```
      attributes: ['ID', 'Name', 'totalDays','presentDays', [StudentDB.Sequelize.literal('(totalDays - presentDays)'), 'absentDays']],

     where:{
      absentDays:{
     [Op.gt]:50 
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you defined your table name as Student(not variable definition, your definition in model)

So it should look like this:

`where: {
and: sequelize.literal('("Student"."totalDays" + "Student"."presentDays" ) > 50 ')
}`